# "the below given sentence" versus "the below sentence given"

Tags: adjectives

I have observed that in some sentences **adjectives** are used after nouns, whereas in some sentences **adjectives** are used before nouns.  Or, if my understanding is wrong about these, in the first sentence they work as **adjectives** and in the second one, they work as **verbs**.

Could you please clarify?

> 1) Please find an example in the below **given** sentence. (before)
>   2) Please find an example in the below sentence **given**. (after)

Comment: The standard order would be *sentence given below*. Here, *below* goes with *given* (I can't decide whether it's an adverb or a complement), so *below sentence given* is utterly wrong.

Comment: It's a reduced relative clause, like most of the choppy chunks we get here. _The sentence (which is) given below_ is where it comes from, and Whiz-Deletion does the rest, leaving a two-word modifier _given below_ that must appear after the noun it modifies, with the words in that order.

Comment: Thank you both of you. As  of now I was thinking that "below" and "given" are an adjective in sentence mentioned above , but according to you these are modifier, therefore could you please tell me what is difference between "modifier" and "adjective"

Comment: "adjective" is old term for the "part of speech" (word) that modifies a noun.  " modifier" is broader, and function-oriented; it includes any word or words that are USED to modify a noun, regardless which "part of speech" they are.  In this case, "given" is a participle and "below" is an adverb (although in other situations you might call "below" a preposition)

Comment: Thank you Brian...I have an question 1) does "modifier" always come AFTER "Noun" or it can come BEFORE also?

Comment: @CharmiSapariya There are premodifiers and postmodifiers. For the lack of a better explanation, I'd like to point you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier. I also believe that most confusing cases you found could be solved by the idea of Whiz-Deletion John Lawler mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Adjectives qualify **nouns or people**.

A new big wooden **bed** (= the bed is a noun.   New, big and wooden are adjectives.)

A beautiful slim dark-haired American **girl**(=the girl is a people.   Beuatiful, slim and dark-haired and American are adjectives.)

**Attributive adjectives PRECEDE** the noun or people.

clever girl(=Adjective before people.)

coloured dress(=Adjective before noun.)

big duck(=Adjective before noun.)

**Predicative adjectives FOLLOW** the noun or people.

The shoes look **expensive** (='The shoes' are the subject, 'look' is the linking verb and 'expensive' is a predicative adjective.   Follow the noun.)

But if we say:

The **expensive** shoes (='expensive' is become to attributive adjective.   There isn't linking verb.   Precede the noun.)

Other example;

The lorry is **broken-down** (='The lorry' is the subject, 'is' is the linking verb and 'broken-down' is a predicative adjective.   Follow the noun.)

But if we say:

The **broken-down** lorry (='broken-down' is become to attributive adjective.   Precede the noun.)

Everything depends of what you want to say.